# Alternate between upper and lowercase, PERL

Tags: perl

I want to alternate between upper and lower case, however I only managed to get the whole string upper or lower, or the first character.
I have not found a proper function to execute what I need. Please have a look and help me out. Cheers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $mystring = "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase";

my @myarray = split("", $mystring);
print ucfirst("@myarray");
```

Comment: What is the expected result? `ThIs iS...` or `ThIs Is...`?

Answer (score 2):

A more general approach using function factory

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub periodic {
  my @subs = @_;
  my $i = 0;

  return sub {
    $i = 0 if $i > $#subs;
    return $subs[$i++]->(@_);
  };
}

my $mystring = "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase";

my $f = periodic(
  sub { uc pop },
  sub { lc pop },
  # sub { .. },
  # sub { .. },
);
$mystring =~ s/([a-z])/ $f->($1) /egi;
print $mystring, "\n";
```

output

```
ThIs Is My StRiNg I wAnT eAcH cHaRaCtEr To AlTeRnAtE bEtWeEn UpPeR aNd LoWeRcAsE
```

Comment: If anyone is interested: instead of writing this: `$i = 0 if $i > $#subs;`, which really confused me, you could write: `return $subs[$i++ % scalar @subs]->(@_);`.  In other words, the code cycles through the subs array(@subs) over and over.

Comment: @7stud yes, resetting the counter to zero is alternative to using `%` modulo.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
my $mystring = "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase";
my @myarray = split("", $mystring);
my $cnt = 1;
for (@myarray) {
    next unless /[a-z]/i;
    $_ = ($cnt%2 ? uc($_) : lc($_));
    $cnt++;
}
say join('',@myarray);
```

**Output:**

```
ThIs Is My StRiNg I wAnT eAcH cHaRaCtEr To AlTeRnAtE bEtWeEn UpPeR aNd LoWeRcAsE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'hello';
my $x = 0;

$str =~ s/(.)/($x++ % 2 == 0) ? "\U$1" : "\L$1"/eg;
say $str;

--output:--
HeLlO
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use a regex substitution. Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "this string, I will change";

# Ignore whitespace and punctuation.
$str =~ s/(\w)(\w)/\L$1\U$2/g;

# Or include all characters in the uc/lc alternation.
# $str =~ s/(.)(.)/\L$1\U$2/g;

print $str, "\n";
```

If, for some reason, you wish to avoid regexes, try:

```
my $str = "this string, I will change";

my @ary;
my $count = 0;
for my $glyph ( split //, lc $str ) {
    $glyph = uc $glyph if $count % 2;
    push @ary, $glyph;
    $count++;
}
print join( "", @ary ), "\n";
```

Comment: In the first solution you will have an edge case when a sentence or a word contains an odd number of characters.

Comment: After reading your first solution, I realized my solution needs to use \L on the alternate substitution...otherwise it won't work on "HELLO".

Comment: @TLP, Nice catch.  No errors, but the result will be wrong for "HELLO" --because there is no further match after matching  "LL", so the code ends up only doing substitutions on the substring "HELL", producing "hElLO", which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. simple if else condition enough for this

```
my $mystring = "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase";

@xz = split( '', $mystring );
for ( $i = 0; $i < scalar @xz; $i++ ) {
    if ( $i % 2 ) {
        print uc "$xz[$i]";
    }
    else {
        print "$xz[$i]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save script below with name `alter.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print@ARGV[0]=~s/([a-z])([^a-z]*)([a-z])/uc($1).$2.lc$3/egri
```

And run script by command

```
$ perl alter.pl "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase"
```

Output

```
ThIs Is My StRiNg I wAnT eAcH cHaRaCtEr To AlTeRnAtE bEtWeEn UpPeR aNd LoWeRcAse
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers already but I thought I'd chip in because I hadn't seen `map` yet.

```
print map { $c++ % 2 ? lc : uc } split ( //, $mystring );
```

- splits $mystring into characters (`split //`);
- uses map to apply a function to each letter.
- uses `$c++` to autoincrement, then take a modulo 2 to decide if this should be uppercase or lower case.
- join the resultant array.

Gives:

```
#!c:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mystring = "this is my string I want each character to alternate between upper and lowercase";
my $c;
print join ( "", map { $c++ % 2 ? lc : uc } split ( //, $mystring ));
```

Prints:

```
ThIs iS My sTrInG I WaNt eAcH ChArAcTeR To aLtErNaTe bEtWeEn uPpEr aNd lOwErCaSe
```

`map` is a useful function that applies some code to each element in a list, and then 'returns' the list that's produced. So if we treat your string as a list of characters, it works nicely.